# How to use different parameter to rerun a test case if the first test is failed

Tags: pytest

I use rerunfailures to rerun test case if it was failed, my question is how to use different parameter when rerun.

e.g. I want to test receiving a message from the mailbox, the default mailbox is Gmail, then I failed to receive a message in Gmail, the case will be rerun, but this time I want to use yahoo account to test.

Is there a way I can do this?

Comment: What you want to do is the opposite to the purpose of `rerunfailures`. To determine flaky tests, on failure the tests should be rerun with the exact same arguments. Why not parametrize the test with `@pytest.mark.parametrize('mailbox', ['foo@gmail.com', 'bar@yahoo.com'])` instead, thus making two tests with different mailboxes out of the old one?

Comment: But in that case, the case will always run twice,  and have two test result. In fact, I only want to have one result, just only want to change to use another mailbox to test only when primary mailbox is failed to receive message.